# Wrong paginate links after deployin Laravel app to shared host

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, pagination

I used ajax to Load pagination content in its frame. Everything was OK in Local host. For example in `http://localhost:8000/exampleroute` pagination link for comments section , page 2 is: `http://localhost:8000/content/page_comments?page=2` and works well.

But in shared host is: `https://example.com/content/page_comments?%2Fexampleroute=&page=2` and links not work.
I guess the problem is related to .htaccess file. so .htaccess contents here:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

What is base problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RewriteBase /` seems like it could be the issue.

Remove it and compare against https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation#pretty-urls.  Make sure in your `.env` file you have `APP_URL` value set to your application url.